# React Router stop working after upgrade React

Tags: reactjs, app-route

I upgrade React from v16.0.0 to the last version to use Hook, after the upgrade, React Router stop working.

This is the AppRoute code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import DashboardPage from '../components/DashboardPage';
import HelpPage from '../components/HelpPage';
import NotFoundPage from '../components/NotFoundPage';
import LoginPage from '../components/LoginPage';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import PublicRoute from './PublicRoute';

export const history = createHistory();

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage}/>
        <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
 </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

I'm getting:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2OQc.png)

thank you very much!

Ori

Comment: Please post your error as formatted text instead of posting an image. It also might be relevant to post your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

The Router Component in `react-router-dom` is actually called `BrowserRouter` not `Router` , so change `Router` import and Tag to `BrowserRouter` or Just Provide an alias and it should work without changing the tag

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and instead of `createHistory` use `createBrowserHistory`

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Refrence [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-chaum-b6chh?file=/src/App.js:261-307)

Comment: Hey, 
Thank you for your answer. 
I tried it already and I get the same output, so I posted the last working code.

Comment: Unforchantly the output os the same :(.
still got: 
"invariant.js:42 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Answer (score 0):

Try not combining logic with UI

```
// ...code...
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// ...code...
const AppRouter = () => {
   const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

   return (
     <Router>
         <Switch>
           {
              !loggedIn 
              ? <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
              : <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage}/>
           }
           <Route exact path="/help" component={HelpPage} />
           <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
         </Switch>
    </Router>
   );
}
```